# VBA Save As CSV & 97-2003

Tags: excel, vba

I am not the best at VBA and a third-party programme has suddenly stopped working strangely. I am attempting to save as csv and save as 97-2003 excel file.

This was previously working but now I am receiving a Error 1004 message. Can anybody please help me?

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

xls = ActiveWorkbook.FullName
Length = Len(xls) - 3
CSV = Left(xls, Length) & "csv"
dlist = Left(xls, Length - 1)

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
    CSV, FileFormat:=xlCSV, _
    CreateBackup:=False
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
    xls, FileFormat:=xlNormal, _
     Password:="", WriteResPassword:="", ReadOnlyRecommended:= _
    False, CreateBackup:=False
    
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

ActiveSheet.Name = "TITLEBLOCK_DRAWING LIST"
ActiveCell.Select

MsgBox "CSV and XLS files saved"
```

Comment: where is the error?

Comment: Hi, the error comes after the CSV. The files saves as the CSV, then never saves as the xls.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps...

```
Sub SaveTwoFileTypes()
   Dim xlsFileName As String
   Dim lengthXlsFileName As Integer
   Dim csvFileName As String
   Dim dlist As String
   
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
    'Get workbook name (e.g. "https://d.docs.live.net/somealpanumericstring/Documents/Book2.xls")
    xlsFileName = ActiveWorkbook.FullName
    'Get length of name (e.g. 60), then subtract 4 for the period and 3-digit extension
    lengthXlsFileName = Len(xlsFileName) - 4
    'Tack on the .csv extension  after "https://d.docs.live.net/somealpanumericstring/Documents/Book2"
    csvFileName = Left(xlsFileName, lengthXlsFileName) & ".csv"
    'No idea why this is here...
    dlist = Left(xlsFileName, lengthXlsFileName - 1)
    
    'Save both formats
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        csvFileName, FileFormat:=xlCSV, _
        CreateBackup:=False
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        xlsFileName, FileFormat:=xlNormal, _
         Password:="", WriteResPassword:="", ReadOnlyRecommended:= _
        False, CreateBackup:=False
        
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    
    'Name the active worksheet
    ActiveSheet.Name = "TITLEBLOCK_DRAWING LIST"
    ActiveCell.Select
    
    'Display a message box with this text
    MsgBox "CSV and XLS files saved"

End Sub
```

Comment: You may find oddities in saving to OneDrive vs. HDD. I don't recall the specifics I've run into...

Comment: Hi, same thing with happens with that. It saves as the csv, but the error comes after that and it wont save as the xls for some reason. Error 1004 which I believe is because the workbook is active or has the same name? Any ideas?

Comment: To be specific the error is: Run-time error '1004': Cannot access 'TITLEBLOCK_DRAWINGLIST.xls'

Comment: Are you saving to network location or hard disk? How long is the path name?

Comment: Hi yes i think that might be it. Something to do with the network. I just saved it locally on the computer and it worked... any ideas on how to work around this?

Comment: Can you step through the code and Watch xlsFileName? What is the full path? The code worked for me saving to my OneDrive.